# Cannot perform installation due to "This application has failed to start because the application configuration is incorrect." error

Tags: installation, wubi, configuration

I am trying to do a fresh install of 12.04 on a system running Windows XP. I only want to run Ubuntu as my OS. After downloading and unzipping the file when I try to run wubi I receive the error:

```
This application has failed to start because the application configuration is incorrect.
```

Reinstalling the application may fix the problem" I have tried too reinstall numerous times and still I receive the same error. Can some one help me please help me?

Comment: You lose me at 'unzipping the file'. You can either download wubi.exe and run it, or the Desktop ISO. You don't unzip the ISO although some archival software will open ISOs for you. If you have the ISO, then download wubi.exe (make sure it's the same release) and place it in the same folder as the ISO and run Wubi.

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, could you perhaps add more detail to your question? If this question no longer applies then you can either delete it or answer it yourself if you've solved the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use Wubi, just don't try to do so by unpacking the ISO image like an archive. Instead, you can download Wubi.exe from the Ubuntu website (where it is called "the Windows installer"), then put it in a folder with the ISO image. This folder should contain just two files--Wubi.exe, and an Ubuntu ISO image for the same version of Ubuntu. Then run Wubi.exe, and it will install Ubuntu, using data from the ISO image.

This was essentially answered by [bcbc](https://askubuntu.com/users/14916/bcbc) in [a comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221923/cannot-perform-installation-due-to-this-application-has-failed-to-start-because#comment273972_221923):

> You lose me at 'unzipping the file'. You can either download wubi.exe
>   and run it, or the Desktop ISO. You don't unzip the ISO although some
>   archival software will open ISOs for you. If you have the ISO, then
>   download wubi.exe (make sure it's the same release) and place it in
>   the same folder as the ISO and run Wubi.

Or you can run Wubi.exe without the presence of an Ubuntu ISO, and it will automatically download the Ubuntu ISO image and use the image it downloads. (This might be seen as unnecessarily wasteful and slow if you already have the ISO image you need, though.)

Answer (score 0):

If you *only* want to run Ubuntu as your OS - if you no longer want Windows XP - then you should not be using Wubi.  You should be installing directly to your hard drive, by either burning a DVD with Ubuntu or (preferably) creating a USB thumbdrive installer.

**WARNING WARNING WARNING WARNING - if there is data on your hard drive you want to keep, back it up before installing Ubuntu to the hard drive directly!**

That said, when you're ready to proceed - download the Ubuntu .iso from http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop.  **I strongly recommend you select 12.04 LTS, not 12.10.**  You may either burn that .iso to a DVD (instructions here: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/burn-a-dvd-on-windows) or you may create a USB thumb drive (instructions here: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows).  Again, I recommend the USB thumb drive if possible.

Comment: my mistake i tried to download ubuntu then open and run it to install on my pc, i tried the download onto USB then boot from the USB as described above and i select the usb in the boot menu but it starts up as normal with windows Xp??

Comment: **Follow the directions linked** for creating the USB disk.  You can't just save the file on the disk, you actually have to run **Unetbootin** to create it.

Comment: i followed the "create a usb stick on windows" link above

Comment: i have downloaded  ubuntu 12.04 LTS desktop then used the pendrive usb installer program to create a boot disk, there are 9 folders 4 text documents and the Wubi application on the usb, when i go to restart and boot from the usb the screen goes blank for a few seconds then it starts up windows Xp again?????

Comment: have now created a boot CD and tried to boot from that and i still get the same result AAARRRRRRGGGGHHHH.............